# How do i get the text value from a ComboBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

This may be something covered in C# 101 but I haven't been able to find an easy to understand answer to this question anywhere on google or stack overflow.  Is there a better way to return a text value from a combobox without using this crappy work around I came up with?

```
private void test_site_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string cmbvalue = "";

    cmbvalue = this.test_site.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string[] cmbvalues = cmbvalue.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

    MessageBox.Show(cmbvalues[1]);
}
```

Please don't rail on me to hard I'm really just now picking up c# and OOP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have ComboBoxItems in your ComboBox, so that SelectedValue is returning a ComboBoxItem and ToString is therefore returning something like `ComboBox SomeValue`.

If that's the case, you can get the content using ComboBoxItem.Content:

```
ComboBoxItem selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)(test_site.SelectedValue);
string value = (string)(selectedItem.Content);
```

However, a better approach is, instead of populating the ComboBox with a collection of ComboBoxItems, to set ComboBox.ItemsSource to the desired collection of strings:

```
test_site.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Alice", "Bob", "Carol" };
```

Then SelectedItem will get you the currently selected string directly.

```
string selectedItem = (string)(test_site.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: first suggestion throughs exception: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.

Answer (score 1):

On load events put

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ComboBox.TextProperty, typeof(ComboBox));

dpd.AddValueChanged(cmbChungChi, OnTextChanged);
```

And get text via funtion

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    txtName.Text = cmbChungChi.Text;
}
```

Good luck.