# How To Link ComboBoxItem to File

Tags: wpf, vb.net

This question is a follow-up to one I asked and got answered here:  [How to display XPS document using a selected combobox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636128/how-to-display-xps-document-using-a-selected-combobox-item)

I've created a WPF app using VB 2010.  I set the comboboxitems via the XAML.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to set the value of each item to a file path.

The objective is for a user to be able to select an item from a drop-down list, then that selection opens an XPS file in the DocumentViewer.  The code below was provided to me by COMPETENT_TECH (thanks) to read and display the value of the selected comboboxitem in the DocumentViewer.

The path to the files I want opened is C:\folder\file.xps

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Try
        Dim sFileName As String

        sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName) Then
            Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(sFileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

            DocumentViewer1.Document = theDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

**Update**

Here's the XAML I'm using:

```
<ComboBox Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Name="ComboBox1" Height="Auto" Margin="0" Padding="1" Grid.Column="2"> 
  <ComboBoxItem>123456</ComboBoxItem> 
  <ComboBoxItem>123457</ComboBoxItem> 
  <ComboBoxItem>123458</ComboBoxItem> 
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the xaml used to populate the combobox?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your posting.  Here's the XAML I'm using - nothing fancy:

    <ComboBox Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Name="ComboBox1" Height="Auto" Margin="0" Padding="1" Grid.Column="2">
                                <ComboBoxItem>123456</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>123457</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>123458</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>

Comment: Ok, are the files that you want named something like c:\folder\123456.xps where the value in the combobox is the name of the file without the the .xps? Or is there something else that determines the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on precisely how the xaml to load the combobox is specified, you will probably want to change this line:

```
Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(sFileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

to:

```
Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\folder", sFileName & ".xps"), System.IO.FileAccess.Read)
```

All that we do in the new code is combine the directory where the files are stored with the file name retrieved from the combobox.

**Update**

The correct way to retrieve the value from the combobox is:

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
    sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help @competent_tech.  I really appreciate it.  
So, based on the xaml I posted to your request let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.  The document to be viewed is a vehicle manual identified by the VIN#.  So the numbers you're seeing in the comboitem is the last 6-digits of the VIN - which will be the file name.  But I don't want to place the file extension together with the file name - so how will that work with your answer above.  I think I get your answer, but that will mean I'll have to list the full file name in the combobox, right?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: Ah, now I understand! I have updated the answer to add the extension to the vehicle identifier in the combobox, which should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank boss, looking at the code you provided - I'm starting to get the logic behind it.  However, the error I'm now getting is this:

_Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.String'.

Does this mean that VB isn't able to convert the numbers derived from the comboboxitem to string?  If so, how do I set the data type of the comboboxitems via XAML (assuming that's what will fix this)?

Comment: I saw a post by @itowlson at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348646/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-from-a-combobox-in-wpf where he was instructing a user to set the string values of the combobox directly in code instead of using comboboxitems as I have done.  Can this approach work for me too?

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: I have updated the answer to show the correct way to retrieve the value from the combobox. But yes, that link will work for you too.

Comment: I don't mean to seem dumb, but in this case I am (I guess).  Where exactly will I paste this.  Will I be replacing the previous code you gave?  Currently, here's the code that's associated with the button.click event:

Comment: Try
            Dim sFileName As String

            sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFileName) Then
                Dim theDocument As New System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(System.IO.Path.Combine("C:\EMR", sFileName & ".xps"), System.IO.FileAccess.Read)

                DocumentViewer1.Document = theDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " & ex.Message)
        End Try

Comment: @KismetAgbasi: Yes, this code replaces this line in the original code: `sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)`

Comment: Oh snap! it worked!  I am, however, having a hard time understanding why it worked - guess I'll be burning the midnight candle tonight to figure the code out (line-by-line).  THANKS A BUNCH!!!!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as answered and click on the up arrow (you should have enough reputation now).

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you use *Data Binding* with that *ComboBox*.

create a class something like following:

```
Class XPSDocumentInfo
{
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property FileName As String
}
```

Create an `ObservableCollection(Of XPSDocumentInfo)` and bind it to *ComboBox*'s *ItemsSource*.

Use `DisplayMemberPath="Title"` attribute on *ComboBox* so that it will use *Title* property to show text in dropdown but since you bound collection of type *XPSDocumentInfo*, *SelectedItem* property of that *ComboBox* with return an object of type *XPSDocumentInfo*.

For example,

```
sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, String)
```

will be changed to

```
sFileName = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, XPSDocumentInfo).FileName
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm using VB but I think your code is in C#.  Also, I reading up on Binding on the MSDN site so hopefully I'll get a better understanding of how to use this feature to bind an xML file to my combobox.  Thanks anyway.