# how to select windows Phone 8.1 Dropdown selected item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In XAML

```XAML
<ComboBox x:Name="CmbVendor" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" SelectedValue="{Binding vendor_name}"  >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBoxItem x:Name="text"  Content="{Binding vendor_name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <!--
   <ComboBoxItem Content="15 minutes" Tag="15"  />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="30 minutes" Tag="30"  />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="1 hour" Tag="60"  />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="1 day" Tag="1440"  />
   -->   
</ComboBox>
```

when I use static combo-box item I am getting data using the method

```C#
string Title = ((ComboBoxItem)CmbVendor.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

but when I change to dynamic I am not getting selected item.

What is the solution?

Note
In c# I called `getdropdownvalue()` in constructor

```C#
private async void getdropdownvalue()
{
    ........
    CmbVendor.ItemsSource = items;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code you've added to populate the Combobox is something along the lines of:

```
List<VendorNames> vender_name = new List<VendorNames>();
vender_names .Add(new VendorNames() { Name = "NAMEHERE" });
```

Then to access the selected item:

```
 string Title = (CmbVendor.SelectedItem as VendorNames).Name.ToString()
```

This is just pseudo code hopefully to get you going along the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. but im getting the below error  Unable to cast object of type 'Row' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.

Comment: @Vel take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348646/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-from-a-combobox-in-wpf it talks about the error. Although it's not too specific to your problem, it's along the lines. I'm not too sure so just take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have the Modelclass like below.

```
public class Row
{
  public string vendor_id { get; set; }
  public string vendor_name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your function

```
var value = CmbVendor.SelectedItem as Row;
```

and then

```
Dictionary<string, string> pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pairs.Add("vendorID", value.vendor_id);
```